# Can't add class or style when scroll to corresponding section

Tags: javascript

I have a menu where I have added link like that

```
<a href="#about">About</a>
```

Now, I am going to that section where I have added a ID like that:

```
<div id="about"></div>
```

Now, When I go to that section after clicking on the link **I want an add a class name** using JavaScript. So, to do that I am using the following JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    
        if (this.hash !== "") {
           
            event.preventDefault();
            
            var hash = this.hash;
           
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 800, function(){
           
                window.location.hash = hash;
                
                hash.addClass('topMargin');
            });
        } // End if
    });
});
```

But It's showing an error like which is :

> Uncaught TypeError: hash.addClass is not a function

So, Its because of this line:

```
hash.addClass('topMargin');
```

but why? How can I fix it?

Comment: `hash` is a string. Write `console.log(hash)` after setting it. You want `$(hash).addClass('topMargin')`.

Comment: OH, What a simple a mistake :)

Comment: It's working now but can you tell me why it's bouncing after going to that section?

Comment: Not sure, would need a [mre] to be sure, but probably because it scrolls to `hash`, then you add a top margin to `hash`, causing it to appear to drop down from where it was.

Comment: Yes exactly, Is there any solution for that too please?

Comment: I am using this site: http://ahmad2020.accountsupport.com/

Comment: Please do some research on the subject, and if your research comes up empty, ask a new question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank You.